# gibberish data in utf8 columns while exporting sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-3

I have used the `db_backup` function from PongoCMS to make the backup of the MySQL database. Almost all the columns in all the database tables are exported properly but on table columns with 'utf8' encoding (i've used `utf8_unicode_ci` collation), the exported data of that columns are filled with question marks.

Following is the function that I used:

```
public static function db_backup()
{

$type_db = Config::get('database.default');
$connections = Config::get('database.connections');

switch($type_db) {

  case 'sqlite':

    $file_name = $connections[$type_db]['database'] . '.' . $connections[$type_db]['driver'];

    break;

  case 'mysql':

    $link = mysql_connect($connections[$type_db]['host'],$connections[$type_db]['username'],$connections[$type_db]['password']);
    mysql_select_db($connections[$type_db]['database'],$link);

    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
      $tables[] = $row[0];
    }

    //Set time now
    $now = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');

    //File header
    $return ="### DB BACKUP: " . $connections[$type_db]['database'] . " at " . $now . " ###\n\n\n";

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
      $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
      $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

      $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
      $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
      $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

      for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
      {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
          $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
          for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
          {
            $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
            $row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#i","\\n",$row[$j]);
            if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
            if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
          }
          $return.= ");\n";
        }
      }
      $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
    $file_name = 'db-backup-'.$now.'.sql';

    $handle = fopen(path('storage') . 'database/' . $file_name, 'w+');
    fwrite($handle, utf8_encode($return));
    fclose($handle);

}

return $file_name;

}
```

However, if I export the database from `phpmyadmin`, the database is exported properly. What should be changed/added in the above function so that the function also exports the database properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try execute DB query: "SET NAMES 'utf8'". 
But it needs to be executed first! So, put next line in you script:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And keep in mind, this query must be very first query after "mysql_select_db"

Hope it will solve your issue, good luck!

Comment: Doing that caused the data to be more gibberish than before. Now the data contains things like `à¤à¥à¤µà¤¿à¤¨à¥à¤¦ à¤à¥à¤§à¤°à¥` instead of the question marks.

Comment: I finally figured out that `fwrite($handle, utf8_encode($return));` was causing the problem. I removed the `utf8_encode` function and also added the code as you mentioned. Then I got what I required. Thanks for helping out.